# How to find Unequal Values from Two Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am doing a left join query to compare the two tables for any values that do not equal each other on f9 and sumoff6 columns ONLY if the F1 columns are the same. If they are different i would like to subtract them. The results i am getting shows equal values that are already on both tables. I need for f1 columns to match on both tables but if their values on the sumoff6 and f9 columns do not match then display them and subtract them. I am using MS Access SQL view.

Query

```
SELECT statement.f1, statement.f9
FROM statement 
LEFT JOIN allocation_final ON statement.[f1] = allocation_final[f1]
WHERE [allocation_final].sumoff6 <> statement.f9
```

Statement table:

```
f1     f9
-----------------
1      135.58
2      166.30
3       40.22 
4       86.46
5       170.33
6       96.40
```

allocation_final:

```
f1     SumOff6
--------------
1      135.58
2      166.30
3       40.00
4       86.46
5       170.33
6       40.22 
7       22.40
8       70.00
9       96.40
10      50.00
```

Results

```
f1          f9                 
------------------
1   135.58
2   166.3
4    86.46
5   170.33
```

Comment: Is there anything more i can do if statement.f1 has more rows than allocation_final f1?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `allocation_final.sumoff6` has a `NULL` value, and the `WHERE` condition filters out `NULL` values.  Just test for this condition:

```
SELECT statement.f1, statement.f9
FROM statement LEFT JOIN
     allocation_final
     ON statement.[f1] = allocation_final[f1] 
WHERE [allocation_final].sumoff6 <> statement.f9 OR
      [allocation_final].sumoff6 IS NULL;
```

EDIT:

Perhaps your join is in the wrong direction:

```
SELECT allocation_final.f1, statement.f9, allocation_final.sumoff6
FROM allocation_final LEFT JOIN
     statement
     ON statement.[f1] = allocation_final[f1] 
WHERE allocation_final.sumoff6 <> statement.f9 OR
      statement.f9 IS NULL;
```

Based on your sample data, this would make more sense.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I am getting the same results with your query as well. I had a hunch it was filtering it out but wasnt too sure.

Comment: @ajburnett34 . . . You should be getting the rows that do not match on `f1`.

Comment: The results i am getting with that query is showing whats similar in both tables and not similar. Its not just getting me whats not similar. Does it matter that both tables have rows that dont match? Some rows may be a few rows under but have the same "F1" value.

Comment: f1 is unique on both tables. There are some f1 that are in Statement but not in allocation_final though.